# SQL Server convert varchar into datetime to select date range

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I need to select a date range from a MSSQL database but the s.ended field has not been set up as a datetime field.  It has been set up as a varchar and the format for the date stored is  `d/m/Y`.

I have tried the below were clause but I get the below error message.  Does anyone know of how I can get round this without changing the database design?

Where clause:

```
WHERE  
   (S.ended > CONVERT(DateTime, '28/07/2012 00:00:01', 103)) 
   AND (S.ended < CONVERT(DateTime, '28/08/2012 00:00:01', 103))
```

Error message:

> *The conversion of a varchar datatype to a datetime data type resulted in an out of range value.*

Comment: how is the data stored? proper datetime format?

Comment: Did you wrap the varchar fields in a CONVERT?

Comment: The date is stored as a varchar, that is my issue.  You can see in the where clause where I have used the convert.  I do not understand where else I should put this.

Comment: As I've suggested wrap your varchar field ie `S.ended`. All you've shown us is your wrapping your parameter data with CONVERT. Kapil Khandelwal has suggested an answer with this very thinking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE  
   (CONVERT(DateTime, S.ended, 103) > CONVERT(DateTime, '28/07/2012 00:00:01', 103)) 
   AND (CONVERT(DateTime, S.ended, 103) < CONVERT(DateTime, '28/08/2012 00:00:01', 103))
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a chance that the `S.ended` is not in the proper format before comparing with the `Datetime` value.

so first convert that value to Datetime and then compare.

Answer (score -1):

```
WHERE (S.ended > CONVERT(DateTime, '28/07/2012 00:00:01', 103)) AND (S.ended < CONVERT(DateTime, '28/08/2012 00:00:01', 103))
```

maybe changing the date to a US style date instead of **'28/07/2012 00:00:01'** try **'07/28/2012 00:00:01'**

Comment: The conversion is fine, because "103" is specified.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx